# After authentication with facebook/google what happens on third party website

Tags: authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0, authorization, single-sign-on

My understanding is,

1. The user on a third party website clicks sign in with facebook/google.
2. User redirected to facebook/google where he enters his credentials and the third party websites' server gets the access token and using this token its gets the users info.
   3.After the above step, does the third party website have its own authorization server and generate access token for the user to access its own resources or can it use the access token generated by the facebook/google for every requests?

I guess that the access token generated by facebook/google can only be used for getting some user info from facebook/google(or for just authentication). For the resources belonging to the third party website they should implement there own security mechanism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your guess is correct. With Facebook/Google OAuth the third party can only verify that the user successfully logged into his/her Facebook/Google account. The third party can check if the login was successful for example by making a request to the Facebook/Google API with the returned access token and see if the request was successful. If that request was successful the third party website can then return an access token generated by its own API for the resources of its own API.

Comment: Thanks LazerBass, just needed a confirmation